# Regex find and replace string from "a" to "b"

Tags: regex

How can I replace the "Connection Timeout=120;" value with "Connection Timeout=180;" from the following string?

data source=abc\aaa;Packet Size=8192;initial catalog=asdfvbfadf;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Connection Timeout=120; Max Pool Size = 1000;Enlist=true

The string will always contain the beginning "Connection Timeout=" and will end with the first ";"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given in javascript since you didn't mention programming language:
`newString1` will replace only 120, `newString2` will replace any number

```
text = "data source=abcaaa;Packet Size=8192;initial catalog=asdfvbfadf;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Connection Timeout=120; Max Pool Size = 1000;Enlist=true";
newString1 = text.replace('Connection Timeout=120;', 'Connection Timeout=180;');
newString2 = text.replace(/Connection Timeout=\d+;/, 'Connection Timeout=180;');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example using C#
If this is not what you need, Add a programming language tag to your question.

```
string str = "data source=abc\\aaa;Packet Size=8192;initial catalog=asdfvbfadf;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Connection Timeout=120; Max Pool Size = 1000;Enlist=true";
MessageBox.Show(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "(Connection Timeout)=\\d+", "$1=180"));
```